# Nested Data reformat

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to use D3js and having some problems getting data in the format I want. What I have is an array of objects that each have a key and values, each value has an id and fields (A, B). I am trying to have an array of objects that each have a key and values, each value must have the fields (A, B). I don't know how to do this.

**What I have**                                    **What I want**

[image]
[image]

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Could you please add code snippets of what you actually tried so far?

Comment: Hello,when I execute this :

    console.log(data[0].values[3].fields);
I have :

Object { A: Array[1], B: Array[1]}

Comment: And this code : var data1 = data.forEach(function(d){return d.forEach(function(v){return v})}); didn't work.

Comment: @Mar.Gar and it won't because you can't return inside a array.forEach(), if you have an object and want to check it with a for... try for(var k in Object){}, plus d3 have a .nest [Documentation](http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) that i think can help you a lot with your question.

Answer (score 0):

if i did understand your question , this should do the work(very rude way tho)

```
var size = a.length; //a is your object 
for(var i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        var inSize = a[i].values.length;
    for(var j = 0; j < inSize; j++) {
        a[i].values[j] = a[i].values[j].fields;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vuLr99hh/